# Find a chart by his title in Excel spreadsheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, spreadsheet

I have an Excel document with numerous charts on one of its sheets. I need to locate a specific chart by its title. Is there a method, similar to using the search and replace tool, to easily find the desired chart?

None of the charts have a dynamic reference for their titles, linked to a cell